# Log4j2 not rolling over file, instead overriding the same file after SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy

Tags: java, json, log4j2

I have a following JSON config, which does not roll over after it reaches the max-size limit, rather overrides it.

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "name": "cool_log",
    "appenders": { "RollingFile": { "name": "rollingFile",
        "fileName": "/var/log/app_test.log",
        "filePattern": "/var/log/%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
        "JSONLayout": {
          "complete": false,
          "compact" : true,
          "eventEol": true
        },
        "Policies": { "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": { "size": "100 KB" } },
        "DefaultRolloverStrategy": { "max": "10" }
      }
    },
    "loggers": {
      "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "appender-ref": {
          "ref": "rollingFile"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which I created based on [this official example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="var/log/app_test.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The `xml` config rolls over perfectly, but only this I'm missing is `PatternLayout`, which is `JSONLayout` for me.

The setup for log4j2 is,

```
public static void initialiseLoggingConfiguration() {
        try {
            PropertiesConfiguration logConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration("app.properties");
            System.out.println("Setting up log4j2 " + logConfig.getString("log4j2.config"));
            Configurator.initialize(null, logConfig.getString("log4j2.config"));
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and maven dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind,

```
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
    </Policies>
```

becomes

```
"SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
          "size": "1 KB"
        }
```

So the working log4j2.json is,

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "name": "cool_log",
    "appenders": {
      "RollingFile": {
        "name": "rollingFile",
        "fileName": "logservice.log",
        "filePattern": "%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
        "JSONLayout": {
          "complete": false,
          "compact": true,
          "eventEol": true
        },
        "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
          "size": "1 KB"
        },
        "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {
          "max": "10"
        }
      }
    },
    "loggers": {
      "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "appender-ref": {
          "ref": "rollingFile"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Reference

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html